# Facing value error whenever I use "magins" and "margins_name" along with 'aggfunc=' in pivot table - DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

When ever I'm trying to use margins and margins_name along with the aggfunc= parameter in code(pivot table) its showing the error as " ValueError: The name None occurs multiple times, use a level number"

I tried removing the aggfunc= parameter from the code and its actually executing the output.

Simultaneously I can't able to run the code with both the parameter 'aggfunc' and 'margins'.

FYI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GkE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq5LK.png)

Thanks in advance
Hamsanandhi Purushothaman

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.